# Dynamic average calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to add an average cost column which calculates the average across different time periods.

So in the example below, there are 6 months of cost, the first column finds the average across all 6 i.e. average(1,5,8,12,15,20)

The next "Half Period" column determines how many total periods there are and calculates the average across the most recent 3 periods i.e. average(12,15,20)

The first average is straightforward e.g.

```
AVG(COST)
```

What I've tried for the half period is:

```
AVG(COST) OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS BETWEEN x PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

The x is of course an integer value, how would I write the statement to automatically enter the integer required? i.e. in this example 6 periods requires 3 rows averaged, therefore x=2.

x can be found by some sub-query e.g.

```
SELECT ( CEILING(COUNT(PERIOD) / 2) - 1) FROM TABLE
```

Example table:

| Period | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 1 |
| Feb | 5 |
| Mar | 8 |
| Apr | 12 |
| May | 15 |
| Jun | 20 |

Desired Output:

| Period | Cost | All Time Average Cost | Half Period Average Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 1 | 10.1 | 1 |
| Feb | 5 | 10.1 | 3 |
| Mar | 8 | 10.1 | 4.7 |
| Apr | 12 | 10.1 | 8.3 |
| May | 15 | 10.1 | 11.7 |
| Jun | 20 | 10.1 | 15.7 |

Comment: x is of course an integer value, how does this relate to jan,feb etc in sample data given business year isn't necessarily the same as calendar year?

Answer (score 0):

I added this step in SQL. But my window function denied taking the variable half_period_rounded. So we're not quite there yet. :-)

[image]

[SQL query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiXWn.png)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you cannot use a *variable* or an *expression* for the number of rows *Preceeding* in the window expression, we must use a literal value for `x` in the following:

> `BETWEEN x PRECEDING`

If there is a finite number of periods, then we can use a `CASE` statement to switch between the possible expressions:

```
CASE
    WHEN CEILING(COUNT(PERIOD) / 2) - 1 <= 1 
        THEN AVG(COST) OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    WHEN CEILING(COUNT(PERIOD) / 2) - 1 <= 2 
        THEN AVG(COST) OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    WHEN CEILING(COUNT(PERIOD) / 2) - 1 <= 3 
        THEN AVG(COST) OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    WHEN CEILING(COUNT(PERIOD) / 2) - 1 <= 4 
        THEN AVG(COST) OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    WHEN CEILING(COUNT(PERIOD) / 2) - 1 <= 5 
        THEN AVG(COST) OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    WHEN CEILING(COUNT(PERIOD) / 2) - 1 <= 6 
        THEN AVG(COST) OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
END as [Half Period Average Cost]
```

Comment: Thanks, this would would work. Unfortunately, it is a cumbersome solution for a large number of possible periods, some ranging up to 30.

Comment: We only see half of the picture, posting a larger dataset to work with would drive better quality answers, your end result might be a compromise involving a true rolling average over fixed buckets approach, it's hard to imagine what the limits of your data might be

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for sneaky windowed function aggregates!

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (SaleID INT IDENTITY, Cost DECIMAL(12,4), SaleDateTime DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @TABLE (SaleDateTime, Cost) VALUES
('2022-Jan-01', 1 ),
('2022-Feb-01', 5 ),
('2022-Mar-01', 8 ),
('2022-Apr-01', 12),
('2022-May-01', 15),
('2022-Jun-01', 20)


SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(YEAR,SaleDateTime) AS Year, DATEPART(MONTH,SaleDateTime) AS MonthNumber, DATENAME(MONTH,SaleDateTime) AS Month,
       AVG(Cost) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS AllTimeAverage,
       AVG(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR,SaleDateTime), DATEPART(MONTH, SaleDateTime) ORDER BY SaleDateTime) AS MonthlyAverage, 
       AVG(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR,SaleDateTime), DATEPART(QUARTER,SaleDateTime) ORDER BY SaleDateTime) AS QuarterlyAverage,
       AVG(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN SaleDateTime BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(DAY,SaleDateTime),SaleDateTime)) AS DATE) 
                                          AND CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,2,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(DAY,SaleDateTime),SaleDateTime)) AS DATE) 
                                         THEN 1 END ORDER BY SaleDateTime) AS RollingThreeMonthAverage
 FROM @TABLE
 ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,SaleDateTime), DATEPART(MONTH,SaleDateTime)
```

We're cheating here, and having the case expression find the rows we want in our rolling 3 month window. I've opted to keep it to a rolling window of last month, this month and next month (from the first day of last month, to the last day of next month - '2022-01-01 00:00:00' to '2022-04-01 00:00:00' for February).

Partitioning over the whole result set, month and quarter is straightforward, but the rolling three months isn't much more complicated when you turn it into a case expression describing it.

```
Year    MonthNumber Month       AllTimeAverage  MonthlyAverage  QuarterlyAverage    RollingThreeMonthAverage
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2022    1           January     10.166666       1.000000        1.000000            1.000000
2022    2           February    10.166666       5.000000        3.000000            3.000000
2022    3           March       10.166666       8.000000        4.666666            4.666666
2022    4           April       10.166666       12.000000       12.000000           6.500000
2022    5           May         10.166666       15.000000       13.500000           8.200000
2022    6           June        10.166666       20.000000       15.666666           10.166666
```